# Why don't links inherit colours?

Tags: html, css, markup

When you apply a colour to your page's body via CSS:

```
body
{
    color: #FFA;
}
```

The colour is inherited by all sorts of tags such as `<i>`, `<b>`, `<span>`, etc.

However it isn't inherited by `<a>` tags.

Why is this?

Comment: because links have they different default color.

Comment: CSS selector for link tag <a> has higher precedence than inherited from <body> - this depends on CSS implementation by a particular browser. See http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/ on selector precedence rules.

Comment: Thank you this makes sense, my bad I didn't see the duplicate when posting.